# Multiple possible values inserted into one column from another table while using the same primary Key

Tags: sql

My title is probably not the best. I simply cant articulate what I'm trying to do in the title. I have about 8 different tables for this project. Two specifically are giving me some issues. I've spent some time researching how to achieve third normal form, but I can't quite see how this may be possible with my current design. I need some guidance to see how rows will be inserted while not increment a primary key per row. I'll elaborate below.

tblONe:
(tblOneId, GUID, PolicyNum, LineNum)

LineNumTbl
LineId, LineName

```
LineNumTbl
1 MCAL
2 MCNT
3 MCCG
4 MCGL
5 MCPD
6 MCTI
7 MCXC
8 MCXU
```

These will be selections made from a user then inserted into a DB. A user may choose one of these or multiple.

You can see my "tblONe" schema. If a user makes one selection, it's easy to see how the LineId will be inserted  into LineNum. However, I'm running into an issue seeing how someone may choose multiple and keep the same primary key..( I auto increment based on row creation in other tables. )

My thought is it would look something like this.

```
1001, (Random GUID), 1234ABC, 1
1001, (""), 1234ABC, 3
1001, (""), 1234ABC, 5
1001, (""), 1234ABC, 8
```

Is this possible to achieve? Or should I just create the table with 8 separate columns for these LineNums?  Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Here is a radical idea for you - get rid of the IDs and the GUIDs. Use LineName as PK for the LineNum table, and PolicyNum + LineNum for tblONe. Give it a try, and see how magically all your queries become shorter, and no surrogate issues whatsoever...

Comment: @SQLRaptor away from the DB at the moment, but I'll certainly do so when I get back. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Unrelated, but. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154251/is-adding-the-tbl-prefix-to-table-names-really-a-problem

Comment: Touché. I'll keep that in mind for the next post.

Comment: I just don't understand what are you trying to do. You talk about user selection and inserts but I don't see how are they related to the db.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you add the key tblOneId of tblOne to LineNumTbl

Comment: I'll take a look at it ..see if it fits. Thanks for the help